# USB implementation

Tags: usb

I want to ask about USB 2.0 implementation in electronic hardware, as i understand USB 2.0 uses endpoints to buffer data into and out from the Host device. And the endpoints are placed on the device connected to the host. Exactly what type of memory is used for this buffering?

Because the transmission is serial, would shift registers be used to implement end points?

Thanks

Comment: Each electronic hardware can implement it differently. Some MCUs will decode the serial data packets into bytes and store them into SRAM. Which specific device you mean? I don't think that endpoints are implemented with shift registers, what would be the point of it, how would you read the data out of them?

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually the endpoints behave like FIFO (first-in, first-out) buffers, but the USB Serial Interface Engine is more complicated than a shift register. It's been that way since even USB version 1.0.

The actual datalink signals D+/D- do not use NRZ coding where 1 is always 1 and 0 is always 0; there are some complicated analog effects with driving fast signals through a long cable to a serial receiver, that require an extra layer of complication. The link has to avoid sending long sequences of the same bit, because the only way for the receiver to know where the boundary is between one bit and the next is when it sees a transition from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0. So if there are a long sequence of 0000 or 1111 then the receiver clock can get out of sync. USB deals with this problem by "bit stuffing": the actual pulses on the D+/D- sometimes include additional bit transitions to make sure that the clocks stay in sync. It's all explained in the USB specification, I won't rehash it here, but the most important point is that USB is made of many layers of abstraction. Even if you look at a USB D+/D- signal on an oscilloscope, it can be hard to decode manually because of this bit stuffing.

The USB Serial Interface Engine is a State Machine (or more likely a whole stack of state machines, one for each layer of abstraction). At the lowest "datalink" layer, that state machine is responsible for converting "payload" bits into actual D+/D- datalink edges, inserting and removing the "bit stuffing" and recovering the clock signal so that it can extract the serial data. Above that, there is some packet framing that distinguishes IN and OUT times, and CONTROL/BULK/ISOCHRONOUS/INTERRUPT packet types, as well as marking which endpoint is transferring the data. Above that there is the level of the endpoint interfaces themselves, which look like FIFO buffers (they could be implemented by a regular block of RAM, there's nothing special about it). At the application layer, the application can send a block of data through EP1OUT and "at the same time" read data through EP2IN, and from the application's point of view it looks like each endpoint is an independent, asynchronous FIFO buffer. The USB serial interface engine takes care of all of the ugly/beautiful details of how to sequence the data onto the D+/D- wires so that each endpoint gets its data transferred in turn, and BULK data packets are guaranteed to be delivered in full with no data loss, with retries if necessary.

For further reading, the USB implementers' forum usb-if.org is where the USB specifications are published.

Comment: Thanks for the details ill go through the docs

Answer (score 0):

The precise details are implementation dependent - whoever is designing the system gets to choose. Eg: if the implementation is by software, then the serial/parallel conversion might be done by an arithmetic operation rather than a shift register as such. Conceptually a shift register would be implemented. With the endpoints they could be implemented as dma channels or as arrays in memory for a software implementation. Conceptually they are effectively a FIFO (first in, first out) buffer.

Answer (score 0):

USB is packet-oriented, so these packets would be held in buffers between the USB PHY and the upper layers.

Perhaps it would be useful to study how USB's low-level data interface, called UTMI, deals with data. More here: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/usb2-transceiver-macrocell-interface-specifications.pdf

The tl; dr version: UTMI host interface is a pair of parallel streaming interfaces to and from the host.

Comment: THanks for the details!